# how io update tomcat 8 in Plesk Onyx Version 17.5.3 windows

Tags: java, plesk

we install tomcat 8 directly using RDC in c drive and deploy war file in webapps dir and it worked fine but we have to append port no after domain name (ex www.example.co.in:8080/NewProject/) to work.

In plesk our installed tomcat 8 is not appear on list of tomcat server.

either i want tomcat 8 option display in list or we dont need to append port number after domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tomcat 8 is not supported by Plesk 17.5.3 according to Software Requirements - https://docs.plesk.com/release-notes/onyx/software-requirements/#s4-1-2

Comment: Question asked 'how' to do it, not if it was supported. It's a massive mistake by plesk, who will lose lots of business over this alone.